# Prove the relationship between the chord and the radius

Tags: geometry

> Let $\Gamma$ be a circle with center O and let A be a point on
> $\Gamma$. The chord BC intersects the segment OA at point D (see the
> figure below). Show that $BC\ge2 \cdot AD$.

[image]

**My take**

I attempt to use some familiar relations :

Since $AO$ is the radius, its angle with the chord can also be perpendicular, hence we obtain the new orientation of the radius and the chord as two congruent triangles $\triangle{OBD},\ \triangle{ODC}$:

[image]

But how can this be used for proving the relation $BC\leq2AD$?
Thanks

Comment: HINT. Use the theorem of intersecting chords to show that $BD\cdot DC\ge AD^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\,D\neq O\,,\,$ we can prove that $\,BC>2AD\,.$

**Proof :**

If $\,D\neq O\,,\,$ then $\,ODC\,$ and $\,OBD\,$ are two (not degenerate) triangles and, by applying the reverse triangle inequality to each of them, we get that

$CD>OC-OD=OA-OD=AD\,.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

$DB>OB-OD=OA-OD=AD\,.\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

By adding the inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$, it results that

$BC=CD+DB>2AD\,.\\[10pt]$

---

Whereas, if $\,D=O\,,\,$ then $\,BC=2AD\,.$

**Proof :**

$BC=BD+DC=BO+OC=2OC=2OA=2AD\,.$